# Rails changing colour of bootstrap list item using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the colour of a bootstrap list item based on whether the correct answer to a question is selected...but using link_to is making it complicated. Advice appreciated. Thx.

```
    <ul class="list-group" id="answered">

    <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>

  <%= link_to(answer.text, question_path(@question, attempted_answer: answer.id), :class => "list-group-item") %>
         <% if @attempted_answer && @attempted_answer == answer %>
         <% if @attempted_answer.correct %>

          correct
            <% else %>
              incorrect
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: try `button_to`

Comment: Thanks but button_to sends a post request which is not exactly what I want to happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create a method in helper file as below

```
def correct_answer(attempted_answer, answer)
  return false unless attempted_answer
  attempted_answer == answer && attempted_answer.correct   
end
```

## Then call helper method in your view

```
<%= link_to(answer.text, question_path(@question, attempted_answer: answer.id), :class => "list-group-item #{correct_answer?(@attempted_answer, answer) ? 'list-group-item-success' : 'list-group-item-danger'}") %>
  <% correct_answer?(@attempted_answer, answer) ? 'correct' : incorrect %>  
<% end %>
```